# Exporting Beautiful Soup table scrape results to CSV

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-to-csv

Python beginner here, first attempt at using the CSV module to export scrape results. The script in question returns several table elements, only interested in the "price" and "mfr-no" for each of the returned products. Basically just want 2 columns for each of these respective elements.

I'm sure I'm doing something fundamentally wrong when trying to write to a csv, just not sure what. I've got an empty .csv file on my desktop named "test" that I'm attempting to write everything to, and I've tried copying over the same format of other "write to csv" examples on SE to no avail. Any input is appreciated.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import csv
import requests

csvfile = "test.csv"
url = "http://www.dabs.com/category/computing/11001"
base_url = "http://www.dabs.com"
page_array = []

html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")
Product_table = soup.findAll("table")
Products = Product_table[0].findAll("tr")

if len(soup.findAll('tr')) > 0:
    Products = Products[1:]

for row in Products:
    cells = row.find_all('td')
    data = {
        'description' : cells[0].get_text(),
        'price' : cells[1].get_text()
    }
    print row

with open(csvfile, row) as csvfile:
    link_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for val in row:
        link_writer.writerow(val)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to open for writing not pass an iterable:

```
with open(csvfile, "w") as csvfile: # w opens for writing
```

If you want to write items from your loop you should open outside and write in the loop:

```
with open(csvfile, "w") as csvfile:
    link_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for row in Products:
        cells = row.find_all('td')
        data = {
            'description' : cells[0].get_text(),
            'price' : cells[1].get_text()
        }
       # write what you need
```

You code is also finding nothing, to get the mfr number and price:

```
html = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.content, "html.parser")
product_table = soup.find("table")
tds = product_table.find_all('td')


with open(csvfile, "w") as csvfile:
    link_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for tag in tds:
        mfr = tag.find("span")
        if mfr:
            print(mfr.text)

Mfr#: FK3-UK
£30.00
Mfr#: PDW0AE-00900PEN
£99.99
Mfr#: FORCE K7
£39.99
Mfr#: X551MAV-BING-SX1017B
£229.99
Mfr#: VE228TR
£79.99
Mfr#: QQ2-00038
£59.94
Mfr#: M6900
£18.00
Mfr#: MCB4370500C2/04/1
£51.39
Mfr#: 79G-03549
£94.99
Mfr#: FQC-08289
£113.18
Mfr#: WN7-00614
£76.32
Mfr#: GFC-02733
£69.99
Mfr#: 2LF-00021
£19.78
Mfr#: T5D-01574
£169.72
Mfr#: X555LA-XX273H
£399.99
Mfr#: FQC-06949
£109.99
Mfr#: 10DR000TUK
£279.99
Mfr#: 10AW008NUK
£268.44
Mfr#: MCF3QUK
£179.98
Mfr#: K3X03EA#ABU
£253.45
Mfr#: 10DR001EUK
£348.82
Mfr#: 9H.LA2LB.DPE
£76.41
Mfr#: 51MF1600AA001
£29.98
Mfr#: G7V83EA REFURB
£199.99
Mfr#: 62151
£27.99
```

So to create a dict with mfr-nr as key and prices as value:

```
product_table = soup.find("table")
tds = product_table.find_all('td')

data = []
for tag in tds:
    mfr = tag.find("span")
    if mfr: # make sure we have test to get
        data.append(mfr.text)

it = iter(data) # create iterator 
# will create key/value pairings by getting every second element as key and every second element as value starting from 0 and 1 respectively.
data_dict  = dict(zip(it, it))

print(data_dict)
{'Mfr#: FQC-08289': '£113.18', 'Mfr#: 62151': '£27.99', 'Mfr#: VE228TR': '£79.99', 'Mfr#: GFC-02733': '£69.99', 'Mfr#: FK3-UK': '£30.00', 'Mfr#: WN7-00614': '£76.32', 'Mfr#: 10DR001EUK': '£348.82', 'Mfr#: 51MF1600AA001': '£29.98', 'Mfr#: FORCE K7': '£39.99', 'Mfr#: 10DR000TUK': '£279.99', 'Mfr#: 2LF-00021': '£19.78', 'Mfr#: M6900': '£18.00', 'Mfr#: T5D-01574': '£169.72', 'Mfr#: MCB4370500C2/04/1': '£51.39', 'Mfr#: 10AW008NUK': '£268.44', 'Mfr#: PDW0AE-00900PEN': '£99.99', 'Mfr#: G7V83EA REFURB': '£199.99', 'Mfr#: 79G-03549': '£94.99', 'Mfr#: K3X03EA#ABU': '£253.45', 'Mfr#: FQC-06949': '£109.99', 'Mfr#: X551MAV-BING-SX1017B': '£229.99', 'Mfr#: X555LA-XX273H': '£399.99', 'Mfr#: QQ2-00038': '£59.94', 'Mfr#: MCF3QUK': '£179.98', 'Mfr#: 9H.LA2LB.DPE': '£76.41'}
```

Finally to write to csv:

```
with open(csvfile, "w") as csvfile:
    link_writer = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for tup in data_dict.items():
        link_writer.writerow(tup) # write key and value mfr/price in each column
```

Which outputs the following:

```
Mfr#: 10DR001EUK,£348.82
Mfr#: WN7-00614,£76.32
Mfr#: FQC-06949,£109.99
Mfr#: 2LF-00021,£19.78
Mfr#: MCB4370500C2/04/1,£51.39
Mfr#: PDW0AE-00900PEN,£99.99
Mfr#: GFC-02733,£69.99
Mfr#: G7V83EA REFURB,£199.99
Mfr#: X555LA-XX273H,£399.99
Mfr#: FK3-UK,£30.00
Mfr#: QQ2-00038,£59.94
Mfr#: T5D-01574,£169.72
Mfr#: 51MF1600AA001,£29.98
Mfr#: 62151,£27.99
Mfr#: FQC-08289,£113.18
Mfr#: K3X03EA#ABU,£253.45
Mfr#: VE228TR,£79.99
Mfr#: 9H.LA2LB.DPE,£76.41
Mfr#: 10DR000TUK,£279.99
Mfr#: FORCE K7,£39.99
Mfr#: X551MAV-BING-SX1017B,£229.99
Mfr#: 10AW008NUK,£268.44
Mfr#: MCF3QUK,£179.98
Mfr#: 79G-03549,£94.99
Mfr#: M6900,£18.00
```

If you don't want the `Mfr#:` part in the output just use str.split:

```
data = []
for tag in tds:
    mfr = tag.find("span")
    if mfr:
        data.append(mfr.text.split(":")[-1].strip())
```

So your csv will then look like:

```
FK3-UK,£30.00
2LF-00021,£19.78
G7V83EA REFURB,£199.99
T5D-01574,£169.72
FQC-06949,£109.99
10DR001EUK,£348.82
FQC-08289,£113.18
M6900,£18.00
10DR000TUK,£279.99
VE228TR,£79.99
WN7-00614,£76.32
62151,£27.99
MCF3QUK,£179.98
FORCE K7,£39.99
51MF1600AA001,£29.98
X551MAV-BING-SX1017B,£229.99
GFC-02733,£69.99
9H.LA2LB.DPE,£76.41
79G-03549,£94.99
QQ2-00038,£59.94
PDW0AE-00900PEN,£99.99
K3X03EA#ABU,£253.45
MCB4370500C2/04/1,£51.39
10AW008NUK,£268.44
X555LA-XX273H,£399.99
```

Comment: @user3093445, no prob. There are always a few different ways to get what you need when parsing, trying to get associated values in one step is always the best approach if possible so the line up correctly.